# How to work with the formset in CBV at the Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, formset

I have a form `ProductCreateForm`. It is necessary to insert the form `SpeciallyPriceForm` inside it.

I have a view for `ProductCreateForm`. But I don’t know how to process `SpeciallyPriceForm` in it either.

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        print('form')
        kwargs = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        ...
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.user = self.request.user
        product.save()
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'location': location})
        else:
            return redirect(location)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ....
```

**upd.**

```
class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    # template_name = 'products/product_form.html'
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ProductsCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('ok')
        ctx=super(ProductsCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()
        return ctx

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        if kwargs.get('slug'):
            category = Category.objects.filter(slug=kwargs.get('slug')).first()
            self.initial.update({'category': category})
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = self.get_form()
        special_form = SpeciallyPriceForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and special_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
```

I need the template as

```
<form ... >
    {{ form }}       /*product_form
    {{ formset }}    /* specially_price_form
</form>
```

**upd2**

**models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name='product',
        verbose_name=_('category'), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
    )
```

**forms**

```
self.fields['category'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=provider.category.all())

def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProductCreateForm, self).clean()
        cd_category = cleaned_data.get('category')
```

**views**

```
form = self.get_form()   #Error
```

Comment: You mean that you want to insert a form within a form? This is not recommended. You should include the content of the `SpeciallyPriceForm` within `ProductCreateForm` in your forms.py and/or models.py. If you want your form to be dynamic, check https://github.com/alvarolloret/django_dynamic_form

Comment: @Alvaro It seems to me that the formset is intended to combine several forms ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a `formset` is really to show the same form several times with different instances.  What you want here is 2 forms.  Add `get_context data`

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ctx=super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
   ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()
   return ctx

def form_valid(self, form):
    special_form = SpeciallyPriceForm(self.request.POST)
    if special_form.is_valid():
    ...
    else: error code and return to screen
```

Comment: `global name 'SpeciallyPriceForm' is not defined` in `ctx['special_form'] = SpeciallyPriceForm()`

Comment: we've called it `special_form`  so in the template it would be `{{ special_form }}` and you need to import `SpecialForm` from wherever it is declared

Comment: Thnx. Could you tell me how I handle the form with ProductCreatForm? If I write self.get_form (), I get an error like Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Category: A>, <Category: B>]>": "Product.category" must be a "Category" instance. Strange, because this is the category instance...